# How can I declare 'AProperty' in a .h file in objective c without include the AProperty.h

Tags: objective-c

In my AnInterface.h file, I declare an interface, which has a property refers to another interface 'AProperty'. AProperty is defined in AProperty.h:

```
@interface AnInterface :UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@property (strong, nonatomic) AProperty *aProperty;
@end
```

How can I declare AProperty in AnInterface.h without import the AProperty.h? In C++, I can do something like 'class AProperty'.  I can't import AProperty.h since it will create a circle import of .h files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a forward declaration:

```
@class AProperty;
```

But keep in mind that other classes will have to include the header for AProperty in order to access any of members of this class.

Assume you have a class and protocol:

```
@class MyClass;

@protocol Protocol

- (void)doSomethingWithClass:(MyClass*)myClass;

@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (weak) id<Protocol> delegate;

@end
```

Because protocol references `MyClass` type, compiler has to resolve it first. Since `MyClass` is declared after protocol, we need to let compiler know that class exists. This is where forward declarations get handy.

Comment: Techically AProperty is '@interface AProperty : SuperClass' in AProperty.h. Will '@class AProperty;' conflict with '@interface AProperty'?

Comment: No they won't, forward declaration is merely there to indicate the existence of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your C++ experience:

```
@class AProperty;
```

Comment: Techically AProperty is '@interface AProperty : SuperClass' in AProperty.h. Will '@class AProperty;' conflict with '@interface AProperty'?

Comment: No. The point of `@class` is forward declaration just like you're trying to do.